# Ubuntu 16.04 using incorrect python version?

Tags: 16.04, unity, python, configuration

When running unity-tweak-tool, startup-disk-creator and other applications, I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

But it doesn't seem to be pointing to the incorrect version of python:

```
user@laptop:~$ type -a python
python is /usr/bin/python
user@laptop:~$ /usr/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.12
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: wx.pth    auto     /usr/lib/wx/python/wx3.0.pth

Comment: It returns `Python 2.7.12`

Comment: my 16.04 is same. python 2.7.12. so, I install and switch python 2 to 3 with this page http://web.mit.edu/6.00/www/handouts/pybuntu.html